# Function from golang c-library simply stops in C++

Tags: c++, go

I am trying to setup a little server-client application.

For this purpose I created a network server and a network client in golang. I created a library from the client and I am calling the code in my C++ program, but when the program reaches the function call for the message function the program stops and never returns from the function.

I tried to send messages from golang to golang, which works fine.

Here is the go source code for the client:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
    "C"
)

const (
    StopCharacter = "\r\n\r\n"
)

//export GoMessage
func GoMessage(ip string, port int, message string) string {
    address         := strings.Join([]string{ip, strconv.Itoa(port)}, ":")
    connection, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer connection.Close()

    connection.Write([]byte(message))
    connection.Write([]byte(StopCharacter))

    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    n, _   := connection.Read(buffer)

    data   := string(buffer[:n])

    return data
}

func main() {
    /*arg := os.Args[1]

    var (
        ip   = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 3333
    )

    buffer := SendMessage(ip, port, arg)

    fmt.Println(buffer)
    ToFile(buffer)*/
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "os"
)

const (
    StopCharacter = "\r\n\r\n"
)

func ToFile(message string) {
    f, err := os.Create("gout.txt")

    defer f.Close()

    if(err != nil) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    f.WriteString(message)   
}

func SocketServer(port int) {

    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":"+strconv.Itoa(port))

    defer listen.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)    
    }

    for {
        connection, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        go handler(connection)
    }

}

func handler(connection net.Conn) {

    defer connection.Close()

    var (
        buffer = make([]byte, 1024)
        r      = bufio.NewReader(connection)
        w      = bufio.NewWriter(connection)
    )

    var data string = "";

ILOOP:
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buffer)
        data    = string(buffer[:n])

        switch err {
        case io.EOF:
            break ILOOP
        case nil:
            if isTransportOver(data) {
            break ILOOP
            }

        default:
            return
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(data)

    ToFile(data)

    w.Write([]byte("Test123"))
    w.Flush()
}

func isTransportOver(data string) (over bool) {
    over = strings.HasSuffix(data, "\r\n\r\n")
    return
}

func main() {

    port := 3333

    SocketServer(port)
}
```

and this is my C++ code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#include "goclient.h"

extern GoString GoMessage(GoString ip, GoInt port, GoString message);

std::string message(GoString message)
{
    GoString ip;

    ip.p = "127.0.0.1";
    ip.n = 10;

    GoString answer = GoMessage(ip, 3333, message);

    return answer.p;
}

int main()
{
    GoString msg;

    msg.p = "hi";
    msg.n = 2;

    std::cout << message(msg);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

I am doing this just for the sake of sience... I am aware that there are better solutions for this (like thrift).

I am completely out of ideas what to do to solve the problem.

I am using msvc btw.

**Update:**

First of all I tried to compile & run the program with minGW, which brought up a NUL string error:
[image]

Sorry can't copy from mingwshell)

Afterwards I tried to return from the GoMessage function direct after calling:

```
//export GoMessage
func GoMessage(ip string, port int, message string) string {
    return "test"
    address         := strings.Join([]string{ip, strconv.Itoa(port)}, ":")
    connection, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer connection.Close()

    connection.Write([]byte(message))
    connection.Write([]byte(StopCharacter))

    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    n, _   := connection.Read(buffer)

    data   := string(buffer[:n])

    return data
}
```

Which lead to the same result on msvc and but a different output on minGW:
[image]

(Sorry can't copy from mingwshell)

Comment: I would start debugging by returning immediately on first line of your Go function `GoMessage` and see if it still gets stuck. If it did not, then add the rest to that function and see which call inside that function will stuck. This narrows the issue.

Comment: @Griffin I tried to set a fmt.Println to the first line of my go client. Id did not reach the first line. At the moment I tried to run it with minGW. There I got at least an error.

Comment: I'm with @Griffin on it. A couple of more ideas: 1) **HANDLE ALL THE ERRORS;** as of now, your function only "handles" the error return of just one function it calls, and it does not really handle it: if `err` is not nil, the value of `connection` *is unspecified,* and can't be sensibly used. 2) `panic()` as of now instead of printing stuff when handling errors--if something goes awry that'll make your program crash and dump a sensible callstack for you to inspect.

Comment: … After fixing the problem, you'd need to provide a way to communicate any possible error to your C++ side and teach it to handle it there.

Comment: @Mango Could you try just returning on the first line instead of `fmt.Println`? If you don't get any return we can assume that the calls inside the function are not the problem and move to other possibilities.

Comment: @Griffin, I will. Fair point.

Comment: Instead of `ip.n = 10;`, try to set `ip.n = 9;` In your `C++` code.

Comment: @putu I allready tried that. I redid the code entirely and started handling actual `*C.char` types into `GoMessage` and converted them to go strings. Now it's working if I compile it with minGW, but I am still busy figuring out why.

Comment: can't copy from mingwshell> Why not?

Comment: @Sean Burton I can't select there, I have no clue why exactly that's the case... I will figure that out if I have time for that...

Comment: You may have to right-click and choose 'mark' to be able to select, then right-clicking again will copy the selection

Comment: @Sean Burton If I right-click, nothing happens. How I said, I have no clue why. I might have screwed up my settings...^^

Comment: this may help you a little: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully